# Access response data in JSONP request

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, cors, sapui5

I have a SAP Gateway OData-Service and a local Tomcat Apache Server. My SAPUI5 Client is deployed in the Tomcat and requests a OData-Webservice from the SAP Gateway remote server. In fact there is a cross origin domain error. So I set the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in my OData-Webservice and my SAPUI5 client requests with JSONP, but I will get an error because the SAP Gateway can't handle with JSONP responses.

My code:
[image]

The error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

The error depends on the incompatibility of the SAP Gateway to JSONP.

If I look in the network requests I will find this one:
[image]

It is the JSON (not JSONP) response from the webservice.

So my question. Is there a possibility to access to this response?
I tried to access via a lot of callbacks like success, error, fail, done, always, complete, and so on. But no chance...

thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(response) {
       //this is where you'll get data/response
       console.log(response) ;
   },
    error: function(e) {
       console.log(e.message);
    }
});
```

Update:

Problem is with your context.. there is some value like _1453458442107=:1
[image]

Check that and [encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) it.

Comment: same error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :". It also jumps into the error callback function.

Comment: sry I don't understand, could you please explain?

Comment: after "?" in the url, parameters should be encoded. yours currently it has not been encoded..

Answer (score 0):

If you set the CORS header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in the odata responses you should be able to access the service with regular JSON (without the P).

JSONP is a workaround to circumvent the same origin policy when the CORS-Headers are not available.

If your odata service uses authentification it might be necessary to set some more CORS headers to get it working.

[On MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) you can read more about CORS and its headers.

[On Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#CORS_vs_JSONP) is a chapter about CORS vs JSONP.

So have you tried something like the following?

```
$.get({
    url:"https://.../sap/opu/odata/sap/ZMOBILAD_SRV/UsernameSet?$format=json",
    context: document.body,
    cache: false
    }).done(function(){ 
        console.log(this); 
    });
```

Comment: Hi I tried the CORS Plugin for chrome. this does not work. My solution was this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome

Comment: You have to set the CORS Header in the responses of your webservice. Have a look at [this SCN article](http://scn.sap.com/community/gateway/blog/2014/09/23/solve-cors-with-gateway-and-chrome) especially the chapter "The Server Side"